# How to filter out last sampler in While controller in JMeter?

Tags: websocket, while-loop, jmeter

My test plan is as follows:

```
Thread group
    \_..other items
    \_While controller (with blank condition)
        \_Web socket single read sampler
    \_..other items
```

My problem is, because I use blank condition, the While controller executes till the sampler errors out. So my question is, is there a way to filter out this last sampler? There are no other conditions I can use in the While controller as the number of times the child sampler has to be executed is not constant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the WebSocket Single Read Sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       prev.setIgnore()
   }
   ```

   [image]

In the above code `prev` stands for the parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) and the [setIgnore()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) function tells JMeter to not to collect the result for the given Sampler.

More information on this and other JMeter API shortcuts: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)